# Null pointer Exception while Setting data to the TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

When I am setting data to the `ObservableList` it throwing null pointer exception, I could not understand the problem. anyone please help me to find the solution.

Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
@FXML
private TableColumn column1;
@FXML
private TableColumn column2;
@FXML
private TableView table;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    String selectSql = "select first_name,last_name from hr.employees";
    try (Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection(); Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSql)) {
        System.out.println("Getting Connection....");
        while (rs.next()) {
            ObservableList<String> temp = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            temp.add(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println("First Name == "+rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println("Last Name == "+rs.getString(2));
            temp.add(rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println("List Value === "+temp);
            data.add(temp);
            //table.setItems(temp);
        }
        table.setItems(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
```

i am getting error in --->  data.add(temp);

Comment: In which line does the exception raise? You have two ObservableList s one: ObservableList<String> temp = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); and the other: is ObservableList<ObservableList> data
Please post the stacktrace

Comment: i am getting error in --->  data.add(temp);

Comment: Probably the @FXMLprivate ObservableList<ObservableList> data; does not work for ObservableList type and your data object is not instantiated.

Maybe you wanted to write something like this:
ObservableList<ObservableList> data = table.getItems()

Comment: thank you, i am not initialized the data, so that it's showing error. but right now the tableview loading with empty.

Answer (score 1):

Before using `data`, initialize the list with `data = new ObservableList<ObservableList>();`

Comment: Thank you, it's not showing error, but right now the tableview is empty. what is the problem?

Comment: @Thirunavukkarasu That sounds like a completely different question, and one for which you haven't provided enough information.